# usb video adapter - wdm command sniffing / spoofing

Tags: video, usb, vlc, x10

I have an x10 va11a composite->usb adapter, works great. I needed another, so i bought another, but what was sent was a va12a. They apparently dont make the va11a anymore. The va12a is upgraded to 720x480 capture resolution @30fps instead of the 640x480 of the va11a.

However more has changed than just the resolution. VLC, or other software of the type (amcap, webcamxp) can open the va11a and receive video. opening the va12a produces static, black with some wavy horizontal white lines. I have checked everywhere i can, different settings, googling va12a vlc, and nothing seems to work.

Funny enough, if i open the va12a in vlc with the static and then open x10's 'vanguard' software for viewing the cam at the same time, the static goes away and i am able to see the video in both vlc and vanguard. Doing this though, the two pieces of software seem to fight over video frames, and they both flash in a strobing effect as one software gets frames and the other doesnt, and back and forth.

So I am looking for a way to find out exactly what vangard is doing to enable the adapter to produce video, whether it is switching a crossbar source behind the scenes that is unavailable in other software, or sending some commands to the adapter, whatever it may be. I'd like to then send those commands or crossbar switch without opening vangard as to be able to get the va12a to work in other programs such as vlc or webcam xp.

Anyone have any ideas on where to start? I though usbsnoop might be good for sniffing usb commands but it seems very cryptic and I cannot find much documentation.

Thanks,
Mike